# With g++ Is there way for a dynamically linked library to be loaded under a specified namespace without modifying source?

Tags: c++, qt, g++

With g++ is there a way to link a library so that all symbols are under a new namespace?

For example, I'd like to use a library in my program which has conflicting symbols with my existing code. Is there a way to encapsulate the linked library under a new name space through the linker, without the need to modify source code?

**Edit**

Here is some more detail:

I am working on a Qt application, which functions as an "Application Manager" for an embedded device. This application links the Qt module "webkitwidgets", which is a library.

the applications managed by this application manager are built as shared libraries, and when they are launched by this manager program a wrapper programed (Launcher) is forked, the launcher uses QLibrary to load the shared library:

```
bool ProcessInitImpl::loadLibrary(const QString& libraryPath) {
    qTrace() << libraryPath;

    QLibrary lib(libraryPath);
    lib.setLoadHints(QLibrary::ResolveAllSymbolsHint | QLibrary::ExportExternalSymbolsHint);
    if (lib.load()) {
        qDebug() << libraryPath << " is loaded successfully!";
        typedef void (*RegistrationMethod)();
        RegistrationMethod registrationMethodInTheSharedLibrary = (RegistrationMethod) lib.resolve("registerMetaTypes");
        if (registrationMethodInTheSharedLibrary) {
            registrationMethodInTheSharedLibrary();
            return true;
        }
    }
    qCritical() << libraryPath << " failed to load!" << lib.errorString();
    return false;
}
```

the problem is that this launcher is suppose to be decoupled from the manager, using IPC to communicate between the launcher instances and the manager. However, the launcher is linked to the manager, which in turn is linked to webkitwidgets. There is an application which contains conflicting symbols within webkitwidgets.

Given all of that above, the only thing that came to mind for me was modifying the launcher wrapper so that it had no dependencies on the manager and thus didn't link webkitwidgets. I just wanted to see if there was another way to address this before going down that path.

Comment: Please tell more precisely what actual conflicts you have, with what external library, and give at least example.

Comment: Thanks Basile, I just updated with more detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With g++ is there a way to link a library so that all symbols are under a new namespace?

Probably not (namespaces are a C++ thing and are implemented by [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)), and you don't specify what *exactly* loading a dynamically linked library means to you and you don't tell anything about the actual conflicts you've got. In reality, it is quite complex. Read Levine's [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) and [Drepper's How to Write Shared Libraries](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) for details, and also the documentation of [binutils ld](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/), [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) etc. Read also about [dlmopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) (which I never used).

> For example, I'd like to use a library in my program which has conflicting symbols with my existing code.

Don't touch the library, or the way you are loading it, but touch your program. It would be much simpler (and you could use tools for that, perhaps code your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) or use [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) for that). Perhaps it could be as simple as adding a few `namespace` and or `using` in your own C++ source code. YMMV.

Practically speaking, how to approach the problem depends a lot on the actual conflicts you are observing and how much you have ...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do that through linker. You can load library dynamically and manually assign function pointers. For linux this could be done by something like this:

```
 namespace wrapper {
      int (*foobar)( int ); // replacing int foobar(int) from lib
 };

 // initialization code
 void *handle = dlopen( "libname", flags );
 if( !handle ) ...
 foobar = reinterpret_cast<declspec(foobar)>( dlsym( handle, "foobar" ) );

 // now calling function
 int r = wrapper::foobar( 123 );
```

Comment: I believe this does not answer the question.

Comment: Why not? This way you can put all conflicting functions into namespace

Comment: What about functions in libname calling other functions in libother?

Comment: What about them? I do not see a problem.

Comment: There could be conflicts. See the references in my answer. However, we don't know what conflicts the OP is talking about. So in simple cases, your answer might be enough.

Comment: What conflicts? I am afraid you are over comlicating the matter. OP says that a lib has symbols that conflict with his own. You are speculating that conflicts could be somewhere else. I am afraid the fact that OP may not understand where conflict is may not invalidate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an existing way to do it? No, unless there's an API I'm unaware of (that's not unthinkable). You'd need to write a custom loader that does name translation.

It shouldn't be too hard on any open-source OS, where you can just take the existing loader's source code and patch it to do the modifications you need.